# No such file or directory c++ boost library

Tags: c++, serial-port, boost-asio

I have trouble with opening serial port
Here is code:

```
void openport(const string & path)
{
     boost::system::error_code error;
     boost::asio::io_service io;
     boost::asio::serial_port port(io);
     port.open(path, error);
     if(ec)
     {
          cout << "failed" << ", e=" << ec.message().c_str() << endl;
     }
}
int main()
{
openport("ttyUSB0");
return 0;
}
```

and I got error in terminal after running program :
`failed, e=No such file or directory`

I checked at function openport via cout that variable path is correct

When I put dmesg | grep ttyUSB I got :

```
[11018.593665] usb 1-1.5: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[15414.150404] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[15423.084984] usb 1-1.5: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Perhaps you misspelt `"/dev/ttyUSB0"` (and didn't have `/dev` as your working directory)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On POSIX-type systems (like e.g. Linux) all standard devices live in the `/dev/` directory. You need to provide the *full* path to the device:

```
openport("/dev/ttyUSB0");
```

What happens when you pass only `"ttyUSB0"` is that the system will look for that device in the *current* directory.

Comment: Thank You, I forgot about that full path linking